# How to go back from one Activity to one Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Main Activity that extends to *AppCompatActivity*, which contains a **FrameLayout** and I used to replace it with the desire Fragment.

However, at one time, I called another activity only to show up some specific information, and need to pass back that information to the Main Activity with the last Fragment showed. Thus, I tried to use FragmentManager, and the Fragment shows transparent; also, if I used that, I lost the Main Activity's FrameLayout id.

To try to clarify, I will put a scheme:

[image: Scheme]

Is possible to use onBackPressed to solve it?

**UPDATE**

Below is my onActivityResult that calls *startActivityForResult*, which is used in a Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            execusaoVistoria.fotos = allFotos;

            Intent startPreview = new Intent(getContext(), PreviewActivity.class);
            startPreview.putExtra("path", fileName.toString());
            startPreview.putExtra("ExecusaoVistoria", execusaoVistoria);
            startActivityForResult(startPreview, 10);

        }
    } else if (requestCode == 10) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            allFotos.add((Fotos) data.getBundleExtra("Bundle").getParcelable("foto"));

        }
    }

}
```

And here, is the code from the Activity that calls the setResult:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("Bundle", bundle);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity.

In your MainActivity you will receive a callback

```
onActivityResult()
```

here you can fetch the info you need.

[How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Comment: It worked by using your tip. However, as I finish the other activity, I need to find a way to get the result on OnCreate.

Comment: OnCreate doesn't gets called when you go back to the activity. You put the logic is onResume() may be

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to what you can do based on what you want to achieve with it. You can open the second Activity with `startActivityForResult` from inside your fragment and handle the result in your fragment's `onActivityResult` method.

The second is to handle the result from inside your activity using the same methods of the activity.

In both cases what you are called to do is to call `startActivityForResult(yourIntent, yourRequestCode)` to open the requested activity. In the activity that was opened, when you are finished and have gotten the result you have to call

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
//in case you do not need to pass data back you can skip this
resultIntent.setExtra("extra_result", extraData);
setResult(resultCode,yourResultIntent);
finish();
```

When this returns you to the previous activity the `onActivityResult(resultCode,requestCode)` method will be called with the request code you specified when starting the activity and the result code you set when calling `setResult`.

In order to handle the result inside the fragment you need to override the `onActivityResult` method in your Activity and call through to the `super.onActivityResult` and also override the method inside the fragment. In this case you will handle the result there.

The thing that you need to watch out for is to call the `startActivityForResult` of the actual handler of the result.

If you want to see a full sample of the basic interaction you can check it at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Thank you Krzysztof! In the onActivityResult, I have 2 requestCode, each one doing your own operation. However, it appears that it is not going to the specific requestCode each time. Sometimes, nothing happens!

Comment: can you post the code where you call the `startActivityForResult` and the code calling the setResult?

Comment: I think that sometimes, it appears to mess with the resultCode.

Comment: I added getActivity(). startActivityForResult, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

try out using intent in fragment as
Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(), anotherActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i);

and for back process, declare parent activity as your main activity in manifest.